# Retriable threadpool by overriding afterExecute(Runnable r, Throwable t)

Tags: java, multithreading, threadpoolexecutor

I want to implement a threadpool that tasks can be executed for certain times by overriding `afterExecute` hook. Can I just submit the argument `Runnable r` again?

Here is my initial implementation.

```
public class RetriableThreadPool extends ThreadPoolExecutor {

  static final int MAXRETRYTIMES = 5;

  int retryTimes = 0;

  public RetriableThreadPool(int corePoolSize, int maximumPoolSize, long keepAliveTime,
      TimeUnit unit, BlockingQueue<Runnable> workQueue) {
    super(corePoolSize, maximumPoolSize, keepAliveTime, unit, workQueue);
    retryTimes = 0;
  }

  @Override
  protected void afterExecute(Runnable r, Throwable t) {
    super.afterExecute(r, t);
    if (retryTimes < MAXRETRYTIMES) {
      retryTimes++;
      super.submit(r);
    }
  }

}
```

In this initial implementation, I just allow one task submitted.

```
import java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class ThreadPoolTest {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    RetriableThreadPool retriableThreadPool = new RetriableThreadPool(10, 10, 0L,
        TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS, new LinkedBlockingQueue<Runnable>());
    retriableThreadPool.execute(new Runnable() {
      int num = 0;

      @Override
      public void run() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        num = num + 123;
        System.out.println(num);
      }

    });
    try {
      Thread.sleep(1000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
    // retriableThreadPool.shutdown();
  }
}
```

In this example, I got weird output:

```
123
246
```

If the runnable can be resubmitted, I think I should get 5 outputs. If this cannot be resubmitted. Only 123 should be the result. I don't understand the reason of this output.

---

I modified the code thanks to nogard

```
public class RetriableThreadPool extends ThreadPoolExecutor {

  static final int MAXRETRYTIMES = 5;

  int retryTimes = 0;

  public RetriableThreadPool(int corePoolSize, int maximumPoolSize, long keepAliveTime,
      TimeUnit unit, BlockingQueue<Runnable> workQueue) {
    super(corePoolSize, maximumPoolSize, keepAliveTime, unit, workQueue);
    retryTimes = 0;
  }

  @Override
  protected void afterExecute(Runnable r, Throwable t) {
    super.afterExecute(r, t);
    if (retryTimes < MAXRETRYTIMES) {
      retryTimes++;
      super.execute(r);
    }
  }
}
```

I have 3 other questions:

1. How to retry the runnable with the original state. In this case, I expected the results would be 5 times of 123
2. How to add hooks for method `submit` just like `afterExecute` for `execute`
3. Is there a good implementation of retriable threadpool already? I want to runnable is retried when exceptions are thrown or callable returns certain results.

Answer (score 2):

I think the reason of such behavior is that you **submit** task in the afterExecute method instead of **execute**, and submit will not trigger `afterExecute` callback again. That's why you see only 2 lines in the output: first one is from original execute, and the second one is from submit.

Moreover, you never increment retry counter, your task will be always resubmitted

```
@Override
protected void afterExecute(Runnable r, Throwable t) {
    super.afterExecute(r, t);
    ++ retryTimes;
    if (retryTimes < MAXRETRYTIMES) {
        super.execute(r);
    }
}
```

Update for your 3 questions:

1. There are multiple options:

   - don't change the state inside Runnable (don't assign to num)
   - create new instance of Runnable (or copy instance)
   - reset the state of Runnable
2. For the hook, I would implement in with Decorator pattern: something like this:

   ```
   public class YourExecutor {
   @Override
   public void submit(Runnable task) {
       return super.submit(new TaskDecorator(task));
   }

   protected void onCompletedTask(Runnable task) {
       // callback
   }

   private class TaskDecorator implements Runnable {
       private final Runnable delegate;

       public TaskDecorator(Runnable delegate) {
           this.delegate = delegate;
       }

       @Override
       public void run() {
           this.delegate.run();
           onCompletedTask(delegate);
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: Thanks, I edited code to clarify the problem. I have 2 questions. how to retry the runnable with initial state.In this case, I expected output will be 5 times of 123. Another question is that how to trigger the hooks like afterExecute when using submit()